# Solve equations like $3^x+4^x=7^x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How can I solve something like this?

$$3^x+4^x=7^x$$

I know that $x=1$, but I don't know how to find it. Thank you!

Comment: There is no elementary method to compute solutions of such equations. For example, there is no closed form for the solution of $3^x+4^x=8^x$

Comment: Then how can I solve this one?

Comment: as an intuitive proof, it may help to graph these functions

Comment: @Victor The only thing one can do to solve it is to guess the solution. Obviously, in this case one notes that $3+4=7$, so plugging $x=1$ in your equation you get a correct identity. But for the general case, only numerical methods work.

Comment: What do you mean "how to find it"? $3^1+4^1=7^1$, thus it is a solution to the equation. The hard part is to show this is the only solution (if it is).

Comment: For every positive $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $c>a$ and $c>b$, $a^x+b^x=c^x$ if and only if $u^x+v^x=1$ with $u=a/c<1$ and $v=b/c<1$. Thus, the function $f(x)=u^x+v^x$ is decreasing from $f(0)=2$ to $f(\infty)=0$. As a consequence the equation $f(x)=1$ with $x>0$ does have a solution $x^*$, which is unique. If $a+b=c$, as in your case, then $u+v=1$ hence obviously $x^*=1$. Likewise, if $a+b<c$ then $x^*<1$ while if $a+b>c$ then $x^*>1$.

Comment: In certain more advanced parts of mathematics, it may be useful to find not only the real solution, but also the complex solutions.

Comment: BTW.  Anyone who claims the "found" that $x = 1$ is a solution is lying.  They looked at the equation and said "Hey!  3 + 4 = 7 so $3^1 + 4^1 = 7^!$.  That was lucky!".  They didn't calculate or figure anything.  They just made a very obvious and blatant observation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here $\displaystyle 3^x+4^x = 7^x\Rightarrow \bf{\underbrace{\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^x}_{Strictly\ decreasing\; function}} = \underbrace{\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^x}_{Strictly\; increasing\; function}$

So these two curve Intersect each other exactly one Point.

So we can easily calculate $x=1$ is only Solution of above equation.

Comment: Woah, good job!

Comment: Why $\frac{3}{6}$? Why $6$?

Comment: Why *not* 6?  If you don't like 6 use 5. or 4.98735463... or ... 4 ..or 7.  The point is max(3,4) <= 6 <= 7 so by putting these over 6 you get the LHS is decreasing and the RHS is increasing (or constant if you used 7).  So as $3^0 + 4^0 > 7^0$ there has to be exactly one solution.  In fact we can use this argument to prove that if a,b < c then $a^x + b^x = c^x$ has *exactly* one solution.  Finding out what that solution is may be hard as hell though.  In this case, however, it was easy as sin.

Comment: Hmm... I guess the one thing this very elegant answer didn't consider is that we have to show  the RHS is increasing **and unbounded** and the LHS is decreasing **with a limit to 0**.  If the RHS is increasing but assymptotic to a value less than the limit of the LHS it'd be possible they never intersect.  ... oh wait.  That'd be *zero* solutions and we know $x = 1$ is a solution.... never mind.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$ obviously $(3+4)^x > 3^x+4^x$ by binomial theorem.

For $1>x>0$, we have  $(3^x+4^x)^{1\over x} > 3^{x{1\over x}}+4^{x{1\over x}}$ since ${1\over x} > 1$ and hence $3^x+4^x > (3+4)^x$

For $x< 0$, let $y=-x$ then $({1\over 3})^y+({1\over 4})^y>({1\over3})^y > ({1\over7})^y$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As for $0<a<1,$ $$a^m>a^n$$ if $m<n,$

$$\left(\dfrac37\right)^m+\left(\dfrac47\right)^m>\left(\dfrac37\right)^n+\left(\dfrac47\right)^n$$

if $m<n$

Answer (score 0):

Defining $f(x):=\mathrm{log}_7\left(3^x+4^x\right)$, you want to search for fixed points of $f$. But
$$
f^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{\ln 7}\cdot \frac{3^x\ln 3+4^x \ln 4}{3^x+4^x}>0
$$
and
$$
f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\frac{1}{\ln 7}\cdot \frac{3^x4^x}{(3^x+4^x)^2} \cdot ((\ln 4)^2+(\ln 3)^2-2\ln 3 \ln 4)
$$
which is positive too by arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Answer (score 0):

By putting  the given equation in the form:

$$ {\left( \dfrac {3}{3+4} \right )  } ^x  +  {\left( \dfrac {4}{3+4} \right )  } ^x =1 $$

we find it is satisfied by $x=1$. The monotonic nature of exp function gives no other real roots.